# select data from an numpy array so that the resulting data follows normal distribution

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to sample/select data(rows) from a 2-d numpy array so that after the sampling/selection a specific column of the resulting data follows normal distribution. Is there any existing method to do this?

To elaborate what I am trying to do, I am running a regression model to predict how much fuel an aircraft is going to burn during taxi out. One of the independent variables is how much time the aircraft have one or two engines shut off during taxi (having engine shut off during taxi is OK). In the data, a large portion of the flights have all engines running hence the above independent variable is zero. So these data doesn't really help when I interpret the coefficient of the independent variable. That is why I would like to sample the data to make this independent variable normal.

Hope this help understand the purpose.

Comment: What have you already tried? What errors are you getting?

Comment: No, there is no such method, because the question doesn't make sense as written. You cannot "force" data to follow a normal distribution, unless it already does so. How would you select a binary array of 1s and 0s so that the resulting selection is normally distributed? What is your actual goal? Why do you want your resulting data be normally distributed? Are you asking for a random sample of the existing data?

Comment: Thank you for your update, but it does not make the question any more answerable. The data you are describing is a duration, which is by definition non-negative. A normal distribution has support on `(-inf, inf)`, so this variable _cannot be normally distributed_. You implicitly point this out, when you say that "a large portion of the flights have all engines running hence the above independent variable is zero." Yes, that's correct, and why it cannot be a Gaussian. Your model of the data must take this into account, rather than trying to shoehorn the data into an incorrect model.